# TASM error when i tried to compile this code

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm currently trying to convert assembly language to binary in Kali Linux for the first time, but I'm getting weird errors while writing the assembly language code correctly according to the book I have.

According to the book, after I translate the following code by tasm, I should use tlink software, but the tasm assembler gives an error.

```
STACKSG SEGMENT STACK `STACK`
    DW 32H DUP(0)
STACKSG ENDS

DATASG SEGMENT `DATA`
DATA1 DB 120
DATASG ENDS

CODESG SEGMENT `CODE`
    ASSUME SS:STACKSG, DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG
MAIN    PROC FAR
        MOV AX, DATASG
        MOV DS, AX
        MOV AX, 4C00H
        INT 21H

MAIN    ENDP
CODESG  ENDS
        END MAIN
```

and assembler error:

```
*Warning* hello.asm(1) ignoring unrecognized character ``'
**Error** hello.asm(1) junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `S'
*Warning* hello.asm(1) ignoring unrecognized character ``'
*Warning* hello.asm(5) ignoring unrecognized character ``'
*Warning* hello.asm(5) ignoring unrecognized character ``'
*Warning* hello.asm(9) ignoring unrecognized character ``'
*Warning* hello.asm(9) ignoring unrecognized character ``'
**Error** hello.asm(12) undefined symbol `datasg' (first use)
**Error** hello.asm(12)  (Each undefined symbol is reported only once.)
```

According to the book that I have, everything should come out right and I should not think that the book is wrong.

The book teaches M-Assembly up to Penium series for personal computers. Is this smell different from x86-64 series?
My PC is intel x86-64 Victus HP Laptop.

the full image of my Book's Example code :
[image]

**chatgpt** AI corrected it like this, but it was useless and did not work and gave a new error.

```
STACKSG SEGMENT STACK
    DW 32 DUP(0)
STACKSG ENDS

DATASG SEGMENT
DATA1 DB 120
DATASG ENDS

CODESG SEGMENT
    ASSUME SS:STACKSG, DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG

MAIN PROC FAR
    MOV AX, DATASG
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV AX, 4C00H
    INT 21H
MAIN ENDP

CODESG ENDS
END MAIN
```

**New error :**

```
**Error** hello.asm(13) undefined symbol `datasg' (first use)
**Error** hello.asm(13)  (Each undefined symbol is reported only once.)
```

Comment: Is the problem with my code?

Comment: Try to change ` to '.

Comment: Excuse me, what?

Comment: Use aposthropes instead of backticks.  `'stack'`, `'data'` and `'code'`. Tasm compiles and links this.

Comment: like this ? 

.model small
.stack 100h

Comment: I am really a beginner in assembly and I even entered the internet and chatgpt codes, but it gave me an error. Please guide me more clearly.

Comment: Tasm has two modes `ideal` and `masm`. Directives such as `.model`, `.data`, `.code` work in `masm` mode. Your code will work in `masm` mode as well. `ideal` mode works a little bit diffrent than `masm` mode.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately it still didn't respond.Ideally, it should work without errors, right?

Comment: Are you actually using TASM inside DOSBox?  Or is this `nasm -f elf64`?  (update: it's not NASM, NASM gives different error messages.)  Those instructions (but not directives) could assemble for 64-bit mode, but running them under Linux wouldn't be useful, the handler for `int 21h` just raises SIGSEGV.  Linux 64-bit system calls use the `syscall` instruction, and are very different from DOS even in terms of API, not just ABI.

Comment: With a bit of research, I fully realized my mistake and that was using the tasm assembler on Linux. I found that nasm and gnu gas work better for Linux. Thank you for your support

Comment: I think Your assembler is `yasm`. I downloaded yasm for windows and it generates same errors.

Comment: https://yasm.tortall.net/releases/Release1.2.0.html    `Basic support for TASM syntax, based on the NASM parser and preprocessor.`